# Deleting row in sqlite database with multiple tables doesn't work

Tags: android, database, eclipse, sqlite, methods

I'm making some sort of travelapp where people can add a city, open the city's page, add a diary-date there and finally add a text (highlight) to this date.
Everything works fine except when I try to delete a city from the sqlite database.
Deleting a city means that it automatically has to delete the dates related to that city as well as the highlights, but not the ones that are related to other cities.

The deletion does seem to work, because the city, the dates and the highlight are don't show up in the app directly after I called the method. However, when I make a new city that takes the id of the old one and add a date that was present in the old city as well, the date is shown twice. Strange, because the highlights actually do seem to be deleted.. Here's the code for deleting all three elements:

```
    public void deleteCity(City city){
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
    List<Diary>diaries=getDiariesByCity(city.getId());
    for(Diary diary: diaries){
        try{ deleteDiary(diary);
        }catch(Exception e){ Log.w(TAG, "There is no diary to delete");
    }}
    db.delete(TABLE_CITY, KEY_ID+" =?", new String[]{String.valueOf(city.getId())});

    Log.i(TAG,"City "+city.getId()+" deleted");
}

    public void deleteDiary(Diary diary){
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
    try{ deleteHighlight(getHighlightByDiaryId(diary.getId()));
    }catch(Exception e) { Log.w(TAG, "There is no highlight to delete");            
    }
    db.delete(TABLE_DIARY, KEY_ID+" =?", new String[]{String.valueOf(diary.getId())});

    Log.i(TAG, "Diary "+diary.getId()+" deleted");
}

    public void deleteHighlight(Highlight highlight){
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(TABLE_HIGHLIGHT, KEY_ID+" =?", new String[]{String.valueOf(highlight.getId())});

    Log.i(TAG, "Highlight "+highlight.getId()+" deleted");
}
```

Even stranger is that the logs also tell me that e.g. diary with Id 1 is deleted after deleting a city and when I add a new one it says diary with Id 1 is created. In my opinion this should mean that the old one is indeed deleted and a new one is added, but the more I delete and add a city and its diaries, the more the old diary is duplicated...
Am I missing something here?

Comment: Check what's returned by `db.delete(...)` and close `db` object each time it's created.

Comment: @qbeck db.delete returns 1 in all cases, so that means that it actually deletes the city, diary and highlight right? What do you mean with closing db object everytime it's created? Cause when I close it in every method where I call .getWritable/.getReadable Database it gives me the following error: "attempt to re-open already closed object: SQLite database"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it! I used a tutorial I found for multiple tables in an SQLiteDatabase, but that one was incorrect. I figured that the problem should have something to do with the tables where I linked the Id's of the highlights to a diary and the diaries to a city. In this tutorial the rows which included the Id I wanted to delete, were only deleted from the table which included the object itself. So the table which links the Id's to eachother remained the same. Fixed it by simply adding

```
     db.delete(TABLE_CITY, KEY_ID+" =?", new String[]{String.valueOf(city.getId())});
```

to the deleteCity() method,

```
    db.delete(TABLE_DIARY_HIGHLIGHT, KEY_DIARY_ID+" =?", new String[]{String.valueOf(diary.getId())});
    db.delete(TABLE_CITY_DIARY, KEY_DIARY_ID+" =?", new String[]{String.valueOf(diary.getId())});
```

to the deleteDiary() method, and

```
    db.delete(TABLE_DIARY_HIGHLIGHT, KEY_HIGHLIGHT_ID+" =?", new String[]{String.valueOf(highlight.getId())});
```

to the deleteHighlight() method.